# Git doesn't push my project to my remote git repo

Tags: git, github, git-push

I never had this problem before. I have tried several solutions online but none seems to work. I understood from my googling that it seems I am uploading too many files but I also tried some solutions(that worked for others) such as: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`. However, I keep ending up with the same error and my project doesn't upload to the remote git repository. This is the error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: What platform are you on?  And what transport are you using?  Git recognizes several environment variables that can be useful for debugging: `GIT_TRACE`, `GIT_TRACE_PACKET`, and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`.  It'll cause Git to emit extra debugging information for various things.  In your case, it might be good to use: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git push ...` to get more information.  If you could add some of that to your question, it might help us help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister transport?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I managed to find a solution. This is what I did:

```
git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

and then: `git push`. It successfully pushed it. Hope it helps anybody who might get stuck on this :)